# 2D array board rules

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm doing a program , it is about an "object" (element) that move in 8way direction based on input.
My questions are : How can I make this element to visit cells of the board (2D Array) only once? How do I make it stay it current position if it can not move according to rules?

Start is position (0,0)
As input it get n-> number of dimension Matrix n x n , direction and t-> seconds. **The other thing I don't get how to implement is input seconds, I get input seconds and directions because based on those I have to move the element into this 2D array list.**

I've completed mostly of the program. I can give you my code here if you want to check it and give me advice. I'm stuck in it and I need help.
I want to print number of cells that are not visited. My idea is to give a number 0 to all cells that are not visited and the rest that are visited give number 1 as value. Like cell[x][x]=1; And in the end I count all cells that have number 0 as value and print count.

Comment: *"I can give you my code here if you want to check it"* - Yes, please. But guide us through it, explain the individual parts and concentrate on the stuff that is important for the question. Don't just throw the code at us.

Comment: @Zabuza check it . i've added the important parts of codes , not the full program.

Comment: I forgot to add that I want to print number of cells that are not visited. My idea is to give a number 0 to all cells that are not visited and the rest that are visited give number 1 as value. Like cell[x][x]=1; And in the end I count all cells that have number 0 as value and print count.

Comment: I'm afraid that this question might end up unanswered. It's very broad, you're basically trying to describe a complete game and then expect help to fix multiple issues in it, without explaining each sub-problem in detail. You are probably better of concentrating on one problem only for your questions at SO, describing that in detail. It's way easier to help then.

Comment: I didn't even get the rules of the game. All I got is basically "*I have a game with a 2D array where the player can move around based on inputs*". And all I could tell for implementing this is: *Build a 2D array, read user input, parse it, move the player around on the grid based on the rules*. And this probably doesn't really help you for your specific issues. Maybe you start by listing all the individual rules using a nice format (like a list).

Comment: @zabuza Described full because I thought they would ask for more details. I can delete some part of it but I think people will ask for more details , or I might be wrong. The important think I want to learn and get help is : How can I make this element to visit cells of the board (2D Array) only once? How do I make it stay it current position if it can not move according to rules?

Comment: Have a second `2D` array, like a `boolean[][]` where you set a position to `true` once the player visited it for the first time. Then, if the player wants to move you first check the destination on the `boolean[][]` grid, if it's `true` you reject the movement and don't move.

Comment: @zabuza I've completed other rules , the only one I think I've done it in wrong way is that I've not implemented it that if there is a cell that visited before , it should not be visited anymore.

Comment: @zabuza thank you for that idea. I've tried it but according to the output it doesnt fit with the expected output. Mind have a look at it , maybe I've not implemented right

Comment: for example : if(nCurrRow < n - 1 && nCurrCol < n - 1 && visited[nCurrRow+1][nCurrCol+1] == false) {
      nCurrRow++;
      nCurrCol++;
      visited[nCurrRow][nCurrCol] = true;
     
     }

Comment: I'm sorry but your code really looks too complicated to someone that is not familiar with it. I suggest to break it down in several methods. Add methods like `readInput`, `parseDestination(String input)`, `setDestinationOfPlayer`, `getDestinationOfPlayer`, `hasVisitedDesintationBefore`. Step by step, then it will be far easier to read and probably very straightforward to implement.

Comment: I don't know which part is hard to read. Also yea I would do it more easy with method but in this program I don't think it would need many methods , since the think program want to output is just the number of cells that weren't visited. Also I'm not using an object so I can construct it with methods. Which part of code you don't understand and it looks complicated? We are here to help each other , and even I get help or not , at least I tried.

Comment: it's not a game tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a *valid* move in a particular direction, the object must move to a previously unoccupied cell, or else wait until the next direction.

You have defined `cell[row][col]` to represent the visited state; 0=unvisited, 1=visited.  At the end, the number of unvisited cells will be the number of `cell` elements equal to zero.

To determine if the object should be moved, two checks must be done:

1. Make sure the next position is a valid matrix position (you are doing this correctly)
2. Make sure the next position has not yet been visited (will show below)

   ```
   // Iterate through all k movements
   for (i = 0; i < arrTime.length - 1; i++) {
      // Move by 1 second until reach next instruction
      for (j = arrTime[i]; j < arrTime[i + 1]; j++) {
         // South East
         if (arrDirection[i].equals("SE")) {
            // Check #1 above (a valid matrix position)
            if (nCurrRow < n - 1 && nCurrCol < n - 1) {
               // Check #2 above (only move into unvisited position)
               if (cell[nCurrRow+1][nCurrCol+1] == 0) {
                  // Move, and record that cell has been visited
                  nCurrRow++;
                  nCurrCol++;
                  cell[nCurrRow][nCurrCol] = 1;
               }
            }
         }
         // Other directions following the template for South East
   ```

Now to count unvisited cells:

```
int unVisited=0;
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
   for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
      if (cell[i][j] == 0) unVisited++;
```

EDIT:  To describe the two issues with the code.

1) The first issue relates to the j loop.  The current j loop is

```
for(j = arrTime[i]; j <= arrTime[i + 1]; j++)
```

But must be:

```
for(j = arrTime[i]; j < arrTime[i + 1]; j++)
```

The way it was moves the object one more time than it should

2)  The final movement was not being performed.  The original code was:

```
arrTime[k] = arrTime[k - 1];
```

But must be:

```
arrTime[k] = arrTime[k - 1] + n;
```

Once you make these two changes, both test cases will work.

EDIT #2:  A way to reduce the j loop

Previously, the j loop would run each iteration to the next i value.  Here, we short circuit and leave the j loop as soon the object is unable to move.  In the second test case, this reduced the number of j iterations from 50 to 28.

```
for (i = 0; i < arrTime.length - 1; i++) {
    boolean canMove = true;
    for (j = arrTime[i]; j < arrTime[i + 1] && canMove; j++) {
        if (arrDirection[i].equals("SE")) {
            if (nCurrRow < n - 1 && nCurrCol < n - 1 && cell[nCurrRow + 1][nCurrCol + 1] == 0) {
                nCurrRow++;
                nCurrCol++;
                cell[nCurrRow][nCurrCol] = 1;
            } else
                canMove = false;
        } else if (arrDirection[i].equals("NE")) {
            if (nCurrRow > 0 && nCurrCol < n - 1 && cell[nCurrRow - 1][nCurrCol + 1] == 0) {
                nCurrRow--;
                nCurrCol++;
                cell[nCurrRow][nCurrCol] = 1;
            } else
                canMove = false;
        } ...
```

**EDIT:  Looking for test cases that will fail**

Looking at your new comments, it is legal that the wind changes when `t=1000000` (the maximum allowed value for t).

Consider this very simple test case:

```
3 2   (3x3 matrix, two wind changes)
0 E   (wind blows east right away; robot moves to 0,2)
1000000 S (wind blows south at 1000000s, robot should move to 2,2)
```

Result should be: 4, but your current code will give 6 because it doesn't accept t=1000000.

If you change the line:

```
if(seconds >=0 && seconds<1000000 && k >=2 && k<1000000) {
```

to

```
if(seconds >=0 && seconds<=1000000 && k >=2 && k<=1000000) {
```

Then you get the expected answer of 4.  It is very likely that at least one test case will push all the input boundaries, including when t=1000000.

**EDIT:  Faster algorithm #2**
The current algorithm can be improved by reducing the number of `if` statements.  There are two important improvements:

1)  The former code had to use `if` to check both a)  Valid matrix location  b)  If the location had been previously visited.  You can use one 1 `if` for this, if you create a border around the matrix, and pre-populate with the value 1.  Because of the border, the starting position is 1,1 and not 0,0.

2)  Inside the `j` loop, the code unnecessarily looked up the direction.  Now the direction is determined prior to the j loop, making the code inside the j loop much faster.

Also the number of unvisited cells is dynamic; no need to count them after the `i` loop completes.  I changed the type to `long` because when `n` gets large, then the number of unvisited cells can be up to `n*n` which requires a type long.  This might solve some of the incorrect answers.

If you study the new code, compare it to the older one, you will see many less if statements.  This should scale better under larger test cases.  Lets see if some of the test cases that were timing out improve.

```
public class Robot {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;

    int n = in.nextInt();
    int k = in.nextInt();

    int[] arrTime = new int[k + 1];
    String[] arrDirection = new String[k];
    for (j = 0; j < k; j++) {

        int seconds = in.nextInt();
        if (seconds >= 0 && seconds <= 1000000) {
            arrTime[j] = seconds;
        }

        String direction = in.next();
        arrDirection[j] = direction;
    }
    arrTime[k] = arrTime[k - 1] + n;

    // Add a border around the matrix with values of 1
    int N = n + 2;
    int[][] cell = new int[N][N];
    for (j = 0; j < cell.length; j++) {
        cell[0][j] = 1;  // Top border
        cell[j][0] = 1;  // Left border
        cell[j][N - 1] = 1;  // Right border
        cell[N - 1][j] = 1;  // Bottom border
    }
    int nCurrRow = 1;
    int nCurrCol = 1;
    cell[nCurrRow][nCurrCol] = 1;
    long R = n * n - 1;  // Number of remaining unvisited cells

    for (i = 0; i < arrTime.length - 1; i++) {
        boolean canMove = true;
        int xDir = 0;
        int yDir = 0;
        if (arrDirection[i].equals("SE")) {
            xDir = 1;
            yDir = 1;
        } else if (arrDirection[i].equals("NE")) {
            xDir = 1;
            yDir = -1;
        } else if (arrDirection[i].equals("E")) {
            xDir = 1;
        } else if (arrDirection[i].equals("N")) {
            yDir = -1;
        } else if (arrDirection[i].equals("NW")) {
            xDir = -1;
            yDir = -1;
        } else if (arrDirection[i].equals("W")) {
            xDir = -1;
        } else if (arrDirection[i].equals("SW")) {
            xDir = -1;
            yDir = 1;
        } else if (arrDirection[i].equals("S")) {
            yDir = 1;
        }
        for (j = arrTime[i]; j < arrTime[i + 1] && canMove; j++) {
            if (cell[nCurrRow + yDir][nCurrCol + xDir] == 0) {
                nCurrRow += yDir;
                nCurrCol += xDir;
                cell[nCurrRow][nCurrCol] = 1;
                R--;
            } else
                canMove = false;
        }
    }

    //printArray(cell);

    System.out.println(R);

    in.close();
}

static void printArray(int[][] arr) {
    for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < arr.length; col++)
            System.out.print(arr[row][col]);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

**EDIT #3:  More efficient memory usage; using BitSet**

I suspect that the higher test cases are failing because the value of n is large in those cases.  It is simple to test that when `n=100000` that the `cell` array is too large, causing java memory error.  So this code make the cell array very compact by using bitset.  Lets see how this code does:

```
public class Robot {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;

    int n = in.nextInt();
    int k = in.nextInt();

    int[] arrTime = new int[k + 1];
    String[] arrDirection = new String[k];
    for (j = 0; j < k; j++) {

        int seconds = in.nextInt();
        if (seconds >= 0 && seconds <= 1000000) {
            arrTime[j] = seconds;
        }

        String direction = in.next();
        arrDirection[j] = direction;
    }
    if (k >= 2 && k < 1000000) {
        arrTime[k] = arrTime[k - 1] + n;
    }

    int N = n + 2;
    BitSet[] cell = new BitSet[N];
    for (j = 0; j < cell.length; j++)
        cell[j] = new BitSet(N);

    for (j = 0; j < cell.length; j++) {
        set(cell, 0, j);
        set(cell, j, 0);
        set(cell, j, N-1);
        set(cell, N-1, j);
    }
    int nCurrRow = 1;
    int nCurrCol = 1;
    set(cell,nCurrRow,nCurrCol);
    long R = n * n - 1;

    for (i = 0; i < arrTime.length - 1; i++) {
        boolean canMove = true;
        int xDir = 0;
        int yDir = 0;
        if (arrDirection[i].equals("SE")) {
            xDir = 1;
            yDir = 1;
        } else if (arrDirection[i].equals("NE")) {
            xDir = 1;
            yDir = -1;
        } else if (arrDirection[i].equals("E")) {
            xDir = 1;
        } else if (arrDirection[i].equals("N")) {
            yDir = -1;
        } else if (arrDirection[i].equals("NW")) {
            xDir = -1;
            yDir = -1;
        } else if (arrDirection[i].equals("W")) {
            xDir = -1;
        } else if (arrDirection[i].equals("SW")) {
            xDir = -1;
            yDir = 1;
        } else if (arrDirection[i].equals("S")) {
            yDir = 1;
        }
        for (j = arrTime[i]; j < arrTime[i + 1] && canMove; j++) {
            if (!isSet(cell,nCurrRow + yDir, nCurrCol + xDir)) {
                nCurrRow += yDir;
                nCurrCol += xDir;
                set(cell,nCurrRow,nCurrCol);
                R--;
            } else
                canMove = false;
        }
    }

    //System.out.println();
    //printArray(cell);

    System.out.println(R);

    in.close();
}

static boolean isSet(BitSet[] cell, int x, int y) {
    BitSet b = cell[x];
    return b.get(y);
}
static void set(BitSet[] cell, int x, int y) {
    BitSet b = cell[x];
    b.set(y);
}

static void printArray(int[][] arr) {
    for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < arr.length; col++)
            System.out.print(arr[row][col]);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

**EDIT:  Attempt to read and process at the same time**
This technique sometimes helps with large input.  Rather than read all the input, then process in a second phase, process it as you read.  In this case there is no need to store the data in two arrays (one for arrivalTime and one for direction).  Lets see if this helps at all.

```
public class Robot2 {

static int nCurrRow = 1;
static int nCurrCol = 1;
static long R = 0;
static int[][] cell;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int i = 0;

    int n = in.nextInt();
    int k = in.nextInt();

    // Add a border around the matrix with values of 1
    int N = n + 2;
    cell = new int[N][N];
    for (i = 0; i < cell.length; i++) {
        cell[0][i] = 1; // Top border
        cell[i][0] = 1; // Left border
        cell[i][N - 1] = 1; // Right border
        cell[N - 1][i] = 1; // Bottom border
    }
    cell[nCurrRow][nCurrCol] = 1;
    R = (long)n * n - 1; // Number of remaining unvisited cells

    int sec1 = in.nextInt();
    int sec2 = 0;
    String dir1 = in.next();
    String dir2;

    for (i = 0; i < k - 1; i++) {

        sec2 = in.nextInt();
        dir2 = in.next();
        move(sec2-sec1, dir1);
        dir1 = dir2;
        sec1 = sec2;

    }
    move(n, dir1);

    System.out.println(R);

    in.close();

}

static void move(int t, String dir1) {
    boolean canMove = true;
    int xDir = 0;
    int yDir = 0;
    if (dir1.equals("SE")) {
        xDir = 1;
        yDir = 1;
    } else if (dir1.equals("NE")) {
        xDir = 1;
        yDir = -1;
    } else if (dir1.equals("E")) {
        xDir = 1;
    } else if (dir1.equals("N")) {
        yDir = -1;
    } else if (dir1.equals("NW")) {
        xDir = -1;
        yDir = -1;
    } else if (dir1.equals("W")) {
        xDir = -1;
    } else if (dir1.equals("SW")) {
        xDir = -1;
        yDir = 1;
    } else if (dir1.equals("S")) {
        yDir = 1;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < t && canMove; j++) {
        if (cell[nCurrRow + yDir][nCurrCol + xDir] == 0) {
            nCurrRow += yDir;
            nCurrCol += xDir;
            cell[nCurrRow][nCurrCol] = 1;
            R--;
        } else
            canMove = false;
    }
}
}
```

**EDIT:  Combination of BitSet and one phase processing**

```
public class Robot3 {

static int nCurrRow = 1;
static int nCurrCol = 1;
static long R = 0;
static BitSet[] cell;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int i = 0;

    int n = in.nextInt();
    int k = in.nextInt();

    // Add a border around the matrix with values of 1
    int N = n + 2;
    cell = new BitSet[N];
    for (i = 0; i < cell.length; i++)
        cell[i] = new BitSet(N);

    for (i = 0; i < cell.length; i++) {
        set(cell, 0, i);
        set(cell, i, 0);
        set(cell, i, N-1);
        set(cell, N-1, i);
    }
    set(cell, nCurrRow, nCurrCol);

    R = (long)n * n - 1; // Number of remaining unvisited cells

    int sec1 = in.nextInt();
    int sec2 = 0;
    String dir1 = in.next();
    String dir2;

    for (i = 0; i < k - 1; i++) {

        sec2 = in.nextInt();
        dir2 = in.next();
        move(sec2-sec1, dir1);
        dir1 = dir2;
        sec1 = sec2;

    }
    move(n, dir1);

    System.out.println(R);

    in.close();

}

static void move(int t, String dir1) {
    boolean canMove = true;
    int xDir = 0;
    int yDir = 0;
    if (dir1.equals("SE")) {
        xDir = 1;
        yDir = 1;
    } else if (dir1.equals("NE")) {
        xDir = 1;
        yDir = -1;
    } else if (dir1.equals("E")) {
        xDir = 1;
    } else if (dir1.equals("N")) {
        yDir = -1;
    } else if (dir1.equals("NW")) {
        xDir = -1;
        yDir = -1;
    } else if (dir1.equals("W")) {
        xDir = -1;
    } else if (dir1.equals("SW")) {
        xDir = -1;
        yDir = 1;
    } else if (dir1.equals("S")) {
        yDir = 1;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < t && canMove; j++) {
        if (!isSet(cell,nCurrRow + yDir, nCurrCol + xDir)) {
            nCurrRow += yDir;
            nCurrCol += xDir;
            set(cell, nCurrRow, nCurrCol);
            R--;
        } else
            canMove = false;
    }
}

static boolean isSet(BitSet[] cell, int x, int y) {
    return cell[x].get(y);
}
static void set(BitSet[] cell, int x, int y) {
    cell[x].set(y);
}

}
```

**EDIT:  Replacing Scanner with BufferedReader**
There is a chance that Scanner is too slow:
https://www.cpe.ku.ac.th/~jim/java-io.html
This may be worth a try:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.BitSet;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Robot3 {

static int nCurrRow = 1;
static int nCurrCol = 1;
static long R = 0;
static BitSet[] cell;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Reader.init(System.in);

    //Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int i = 0;


    int n = Reader.nextInt();
    int k = Reader.nextInt();

    // Add a border around the matrix with values of 1
    int N = n + 2;
    cell = new BitSet[N];
    for (i = 0; i < cell.length; i++)
        cell[i] = new BitSet(N);

    for (i = 0; i < cell.length; i++) {
        set(cell, 0, i);
        set(cell, i, 0);
        set(cell, i, N-1);
        set(cell, N-1, i);
    }
    set(cell, nCurrRow, nCurrCol);

    R = (long)n * n - 1; // Number of remaining unvisited cells

    int sec1 = Reader.nextInt();
    int sec2 = 0;
    String dir1 = Reader.next();
    String dir2 = "";

    for (i = 0; i < k - 1; i++) {

        sec2 = Reader.nextInt();
        dir2 = Reader.next();
        move(sec2-sec1, dir1);
        dir1 = dir2;
        sec1 = sec2;

    }
    move(n, dir1);

    System.out.println(R);

}

static void move(int t, String dir1) {
    boolean canMove = true;
    int xDir = 0;
    int yDir = 0;
    if (dir1.equals("SE")) {
        xDir = 1;
        yDir = 1;
    } else if (dir1.equals("NE")) {
        xDir = 1;
        yDir = -1;
    } else if (dir1.equals("E")) {
        xDir = 1;
    } else if (dir1.equals("N")) {
        yDir = -1;
    } else if (dir1.equals("NW")) {
        xDir = -1;
        yDir = -1;
    } else if (dir1.equals("W")) {
        xDir = -1;
    } else if (dir1.equals("SW")) {
        xDir = -1;
        yDir = 1;
    } else if (dir1.equals("S")) {
        yDir = 1;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < t && canMove; j++) {
        if (!isSet(cell,nCurrRow + yDir, nCurrCol + xDir)) {
            nCurrRow += yDir;
            nCurrCol += xDir;
            set(cell, nCurrRow, nCurrCol);
            R--;
        } else
            canMove = false;
    }
}

static boolean isSet(BitSet[] cell, int x, int y) {
    return cell[x].get(y);
}
static void set(BitSet[] cell, int x, int y) {
    cell[x].set(y);
}

static class Reader {
    static BufferedReader reader;
    static StringTokenizer tokenizer;

    /** call this method to initialize reader for InputStream */
    static void init(InputStream input) {
        reader = new BufferedReader(
                     new InputStreamReader(input) );
        tokenizer = new StringTokenizer("");
    }

    /** get next word */
    static String next() throws IOException {
        while ( ! tokenizer.hasMoreTokens() ) {
            //TODO add check for eof if necessary
            tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(
                   reader.readLine() );
        }
        return tokenizer.nextToken();
    }

    static int nextInt() throws IOException {
        return Integer.parseInt( next() );
    }

    static double nextDouble() throws IOException {
        return Double.parseDouble( next() );
    }
}
}
```

**EDIT: Using a Set to store visited cells**
It turns out that when `n` is large, creating BitSets is an expensive process.  About 1.4s was taken just to create the array of BitSets.  So arrays don't work, and BitSet creation is slow.  After some thought, I realized that a regular `HashSet<Long>` should work to store visited cells, and it doesn't have the same cost to create it.

```
public class Robot4 {

static int nCurrRow = 1;
static int nCurrCol = 1;
static long R = 0;
static Set<Long> cell;
static long N;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Reader.init(System.in);

    int i = 0;
    int n = Reader.nextInt();
    int k = Reader.nextInt();

    // Add a border around the matrix with values of 1
    N = n + 2L;
    cell = new HashSet<Long>(1000000);

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        set(0, i);
        set(i, 0);
        set(i, n+1);
        set(n+1, i);
    }
    set(nCurrRow, nCurrCol);

    R = (long)n * n - 1; // Number of remaining unvisited cells

    int sec1 = Reader.nextInt();
    int sec2 = 0;
    String dir1 = Reader.next();
    String dir2 = "";

    for (i = 0; i < k - 1; i++) {

        sec2 = Reader.nextInt();
        dir2 = Reader.next();
        move(sec2-sec1, dir1);
        dir1 = dir2;
        sec1 = sec2;

    }
    move(n, dir1);

    System.out.println(R);

}

static void move(int t, String dir1) {
    boolean canMove = true;
    int xDir = 0;
    int yDir = 0;
    if (dir1.equals("SE")) {
        xDir = 1;
        yDir = 1;
    } else if (dir1.equals("NE")) {
        xDir = 1;
        yDir = -1;
    } else if (dir1.equals("E")) {
        xDir = 1;
    } else if (dir1.equals("N")) {
        yDir = -1;
    } else if (dir1.equals("NW")) {
        xDir = -1;
        yDir = -1;
    } else if (dir1.equals("W")) {
        xDir = -1;
    } else if (dir1.equals("SW")) {
        xDir = -1;
        yDir = 1;
    } else if (dir1.equals("S")) {
        yDir = 1;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < t && canMove; j++) {
        if (!isSet(nCurrRow + yDir, nCurrCol + xDir)) {
            nCurrRow += yDir;
            nCurrCol += xDir;
            set(nCurrRow, nCurrCol);
            R--;
        } else
            canMove = false;
    }
}

static boolean isSet(int x, int y) {
    return cell.contains(indexId(x,y));
}
static void set(int x, int y) {
    cell.add(indexId(x,y));
}
static long indexId(int x, int y) {
    return x*N+y;
}

static class Reader {
    static BufferedReader reader;
    static StringTokenizer tokenizer;

    /** call this method to initialize reader for InputStream */
    static void init(InputStream input) {
        reader = new BufferedReader(
                     new InputStreamReader(input) );
        tokenizer = new StringTokenizer("");
    }

    /** get next word */
    static String next() throws IOException {
        while ( ! tokenizer.hasMoreTokens() ) {
            tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(
                   reader.readLine() );
        }
        return tokenizer.nextToken();
    }

    static int nextInt() throws IOException {
        return Integer.parseInt( next() );
    }

    static double nextDouble() throws IOException {
        return Double.parseDouble( next() );
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hello Sir! First of all thank you for your reply. I have a question  : For every check I have to make a new if? Why not all checks in only 1 if statement?

Comment: also I've modified code as you said but the output was not the right one. Do you want me to publish here the code so you can have a look and tell me where is the problem?

Comment: Yes please post all code and describe what the correct output should be and what you are getting.  Can you also show the one if statement? Thanks

Comment: sure thing , I'll edit the post -> adding full code.

Comment: I have the first test case working (got 13).  Now working on the second

Comment: Thank you! If you want a picture for the second sample , how it travel over that 2D array let me know

Comment: OK, I have both working.  I'll explain the two fixes in the answer.

Comment: thank you so much. I have another question: How can I make this program run more faster , finding output ,increase the performance and perhaps reduce the amount of memory being used?

Comment: The `j` loop could be faster.  For example sometimes the request is move in a direction which is already blocked, or off the matrix.  To optimize would be stop the j loop as soon as possible.  I don't see any excessive memory being used..

Comment: how can I make the J loop faster? could you please give me an example?

Comment: There is now a second edit to the answer, to show how to abort the j loop as soon as the object can not move.

Comment: hey mate , i get a wrong result for some other test cases. Could you check it again please?

Comment: its an competition problem

Comment: What is the competition name? If I can't access I will review the code again in the morning looking for strange cases

Comment: I think those rules included in code of program. Anyway thank you so much , and do it when you have time :) Thanks

Comment: So I have a very simple way to make the program fail, when k=1.  You have posted all the rules of the game, but can you also post the conditions on both n and k?  Also is it guaranteed that t will be sorted?

Comment: yes I can post also conditions:  3<=n<=100000   , 2<=k<=1000000 , 0<=seconds<=1000000 , seconds(0)=0<seconds(1)<...<seconds(k-1)

Comment: I was able to find a failed test case (see revised answer).  Maybe there are more, but this is surely a case that was going to fail.

Comment: I've tried Input n=3 k=2  , seconds1=0  direction1=S , seconds2=1 direction2=N , and it gives output number 6. Look screenshot -> https://imgur.com/a/FNRRO . It's wrong output , I think implement of seconds is not correct.

Comment: Still thinking about this!  Trying to come up with a test case to prove something is wrong.  Your screen shot shows `seconds2=2` - which would mean that `output=6` is correct.  if seconds2=1, then `output=7` - is this what you get?  If you are able to figure out what the input for any case that fails is, I'd love to see it.  I will also try to figure out a faster algorithm.  It is really hard when I can't see the input...

Comment: Yea ouput must be 7. I'll show you matrix with graph and how it moves in that case.

Comment: I have to leave for a few hours.  I have a faster algorithm ready - want you to try it, but I want to test it later first on a few test cases.  Will post it later tonight.

Comment: Still gives wrong answer -> https://imgur.com/a/Yo6dh also now it terminated it due time 4s before was due time 1s.

Comment: Probably test cases higher than 15 use a large `n`.  That will cause a memory error (test for n=100000 - you will see).  So above is new code that compacts the cell memory space by using BitSets.  I am hopeful that more test cases will pass now.

Comment: It didnt pass test cases again also terminated it due time 4s again. https://imgur.com/a/dW2Xz And yea I think you are very right about memory error but it still gives a time 4s which is more higher than the ones before 1s

Comment: I've tried equalsIgnoreCase(); but yea it wasnt part of last strange cases that gives wrong result

Comment: I found another problem.  `long R = n * n - 1` must be `long R = (long)n * n  - 1`.

Comment: Yea that was a problem that solved and some cases success , only 6 more test case terminated due to timeout , screenshot -> https://imgur.com/a/VkRCW

Comment: I think it is safe to say now, in hindsight, that the algorithms have been correct, except when `n` was large the unvisited counter had to be of type `long`.  It would be interesting to revisit some older code attempts and see if they are faster.  I think the latest code is the fastest, but it wouldn't hurt to try older making sure the counter is long.

Comment: As I saw it the older code is more faster cause it has less for loop. Also can switch case make it more faster?

Comment: I'm running out of ideas!  But there is a good reason to try the latest edit - it might speed up the result.  I went back to arrays for now - I don't even know if the BitSets are needed.  A switch should not help much - but feel free to try!  Did you find any older code works better?

Comment: I've tried older code but it doesnt work without BitSets. Also the lastest edit you made is more faster but it gives wrong answer , I think it needs BitSets.   https://imgur.com/a/Yz2ns

Comment: Makes sense (n must be large enough to cause memory error).  Good that you confirmed.  The latest edit combines one phase processing (for speed) and BitSets (for compact memory footprint).

Comment: Lastest edit -> https://imgur.com/a/YD1uq  , yea n also seconds must be large in last 6 test cases. I'll look up if I make an edit in code and try it

Comment: Ah ... what happened?  So many errors now.  Are you fixing them?  It is hard for me since I can't test against the input.  The latest code is really just a combination of earlier code that did work well.  Good luck finding the problems.

Comment: I don't know what happened. Code is same , I'm trying test case 0 since we have input sample.

Comment: I think problem might be at cell (0,0). The result(output) of test case 0 is 12 , it should be 13

Comment: Yes!  You are correct.  This line is missing `  set(cell, nCurrRow, nCurrCol);`.  Answer has been edited.

Comment: Thank you! Now it terminated due timeout. I've tried two times , look screenshot -> https://imgur.com/a/Bv5wm , https://imgur.com/a/ZomGp

Comment: There are several articles which suggest that java Scanner is too slow for competition questions with lots of reading.  So I have changed to read using BufferedReader.  Maybe it will help with the timeouts.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've tried three times with lastest code that include BufferedReader , here are screenshots -> 1st time https://imgur.com/a/06SpM                                                          second try ->https://imgur.com/a/JSIpz                                             
 and third try ->https://imgur.com/a/qMRrt   .It's so strange.                                                               
I'll try to change if else statement with switch. I think the last test case might give timeout error because seconds should be long.

Comment: You are probably tired of trying new things... I really wish I could test myself and save you this work.  It might be possible that the robot is getting trapped and there is no use reading all the extra `k` lines.  The code above will abort if the robot is trapped.  If you figure anything out I would appreciate knowing what it is.  This is a difficult problem because of the size of `n`, `t` and `k`.

Comment: I'm searching for challenges with 3 input and larger to see how they handle it. I'm a bit tired but I can try any time it. Just don't want you to be tired to find and solve this problem (don't want to waste your free time). If I'll figure you I'll let you know

Comment: About trapped edit : It didnt compile in first because you forgot to add cell as parameter in method  (isSet(cell,nCurrRow-1, nCurrCol-1). Anyway fixed it , tried it and Status: Terminated due to timeout every time I tried it.

Comment: Sorry.  I posted that method from different code I was testing.  The trap detection did appear to work on my test cases.  The code is above.  I don't expect it to help, but maybe one or two of the remaining timeouts will work.  I won't bother you with any more unless I can think of something significant.  Thanks for all your tries...

Comment: No problem , you helped me so much and you are helping me, you are not bothering me , you can tell me anytime for lastest code to test out and I'll test as soon as possible. I've testest the one with trap detection in test case 0 and test case 1 it gives "false" https://imgur.com/a/1bv7Y https://imgur.com/a/YYZDM  . Then I tried making  System.out.println(isTrapped()); as comment // -> this is what it gives https://imgur.com/a/ff9VI , all lastest test cases no more runtime error just wrong answer.

Comment: mmm tried again and it gives runetime error :/ https://imgur.com/a/lI9pN

Comment: When you have time, please try the latest edit.  I changed approach and went to a `Set<Long>`.  The lookup time should be close to `O(1)` so I remain hopeful a large dataset will be efficient.

Comment: I don't know what I am going to do now... :)   The array lookup was also `O(1)` but didn't fit, and the BitSet is fast too, but too expensive to create.  It just took time to think about it, and find the correct approach.  Thanks and good luck with future challenges.  Cheers